# Looking for a connector word between sentences where the second sentence gives more detail to the first

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm looking for a connector word between these two sentences along the lines of where, whereas, whereby, etc. Couldn't quite come up with the appropriate word here.

"In the cli, the keywords relevant to ldaps are 'ssl-connection' and 'protocol'. Setting the latter to 'ldaps' or 'starttls' automatically enables the former."

Comment: What *specifically* did you have in mind?

Comment: Just a way to connect the two sentences, combining them into one using a connector word such that the logic flows. @HotLicks In this case, the second sentence provides more details to the first, in a way, but doesn't quite explain the first.

Comment: This is a **terrible** place to use "former" and "latter". You might as well ask your readers to calculate the keywords. Try _Setting 'ssl-connection' to 'ldaps' or 'starttls' automatically enables the 'protocol' keyword._ If that's not what you mean to say, rethink what you **do** mean to say.

Comment: Like, I do't proceed to explain the first sentence. I just provide some necessary details about certain terms introduced in the first.

Comment: @JohnLawler Note that these are settings, key-value, key-value. And 'enables' is a technical jargon meaning setting something to value "enable". Could you explain why this is a confusing / particularly inappropriate usage of former and latter? The structure, or what I'm trying to say, is essentially "we have settings A and B, setting the latter to C automatically enables the former". Why would this be interpreted the other way around, like you do? Thanks.

Comment: I have nothing to say about the way you comment your code. But if this sentence is designed to be read and understood by someone who doesn't have access to your source code, there's a whole lot of assumptions you might want to specify for them, if you care whether they follow the directions.

Comment: In the CLI, the *protocol* setting is linked to the *ssl-connection* setting.  When the *'protocol'* is set to either *'ldaps'* or *'starttls'*,  the *ssl-connection* setting is automatically enabled.

Comment: Short sentences are better than long sentences. Connection here is not the right approach.  TBH, it doesn’t look as if the behavior of this CLI has been fully thought through. It looks like it has the ability to implicitly set some of its parameters based on the presence of others. This raises the question of what happens when incompatible settings are attempted. The best approach is to describe the general property (implicit selection) first, and then offer examples “For example,if the protocol is set to X...”. The problem here is that you are trying to write generally at too low a level.

Comment: @grouchdoug - And what specifically is wrong with "specifically"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection that does not break the flow but necessitates a means of "selection" of "protocol" is the use of a relative pronoun (introducing a relative clause); the construction allowing that is "*the latter of which*", but as can be seen in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+latter+of+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20latter%20of%20which%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20latter%20of%20which%3B%2Cc0), its use has never stopped decreasing and is nowadays not very important; nevertheless, as this [page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+latter+of+which%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en,sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC4fuOsu_vAhWs4IUKHSeBAaEQpwUIJA&biw=1920&bih=1005&dpr=1) will show, it is commonly used in modern scholarly literature.

([example](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Isis_Unveiled/oOZ1BwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+latter+of+which%22&pg=PT830&printsec=frontcover)) There was an Upper, a Lower, and a Western India, the latter of which is now Persia-Iran. The countries now named Thibet, Mongolia, and Great

- In the cli, the keywords relevant to ldaps are 'ssl-connection' and 'protocol', the latter of which, if set to 'ldaps' or 'starttls', automatically enables the former.